# Why NULL terminated string's length is smaller than expected in C?

Tags: c, string

There is code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  char *str = calloc(3, sizeof(char));
  str[2] = '\0';
  
  printf("%ld", strlen(str));

  free(str);
}
```

Expected output `2`
Actual output `0`

Why?

As far as I understood strlen counts symbols before \0. Maybe str[0] and str[1] are already '\0'?

Comment: `calloc()` ... "_Maybe str[0] and str[1] are already '\0'_" ... Guaranteed... (Or, maybe `str` is set to `NULL` because `calloc()` failed for some reason...)

Comment: The character `'\0'` is equal to the integer value `0`. And `calloc` fills all the memory with zeros.

Comment: @Fe2O3 I've replaced with malloc and the result is the same

Comment: `malloc()` will, if it can, return a pointer to a block of heap of the size requested... There is NO initialisation of those bytes. This time you happened to get the same result. Next time might be different.

Comment: malloc doesn't zero the memory. calloc guarantees zeroing.

Comment: While we're on the subject, please note that `realloc()` does not know which function may have been used for an initial allocation. If you grow a region via `realloc()` those additional bytes will not be initialised to NUL, even if you first used `calloc()` to grab the block.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`calloc()` initializes allocated memory with all \0. You then set the last byte to \0 - it's already that value from initialization.

`strlen()` counts the chars before the first \0. Since the very first char is already \0, the length is zero.

In contrast, `malloc()` allocates uninitialized memory. However, that memory may contain any random data including any number of zeroes, even all zeroes.